# P=NP, isn't it?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions, satisfiability, p-vs-np

Cook and Levin showed in 1971 how deterministically in polynomial time from every non deterministic Turing machine **M**, that halts in polynomial number of moves/steps, and string **w** to create the boolean formula $\Phi_{M,w}$ in **conjunctive normal form** that is **true** for each **accept** path/route of **M** on **w** and **false** for each **reject** path/route of **M** on **w** and therefore $\Phi_{M,w}$ is **satisfiable** if and only if **M** accepts **w**.

Suppose $NTM_{CNFFAL}$ is non deterministic Turing machine that decides in polynomial time the language **CNFFAL**, that is the language of all strings that are encoding of **falsifiable** boolean formulas in **conjunctive normal form**, by just guessing truth assignment that evaluates the input boolean formula to **false**.

Let **f** be any boolean formula in **conjunctive normal form**.

Therefore $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}\equiv\lnot f$ since Cook and Levin reduction is **parsimonious** and $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is also in **conjunctive normal form**.

Therefore **f** is **falsifiable** if and only if $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is **satisfiable**.

Therefore **f** is **satisfiable** if and only if $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is **falsifiable**.

This suppose to show that $CNFSAT\le_PCNFFAL$, where **CNFSAT** is the language of all strings that are encoding of **satisfiable** boolean formula in **conjunctive normal form**, also show that **CNFFAL** is NP Complete, since **CNFSAT** is already NP Complete and we all know that $CNFFAL\in\Bbb{P}$.

Therefore $\Bbb{P=NP}$, isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: I find all the bold-faced **words** a little bit **overwhelming**, don't **you**?

Comment: It hurts my eyes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments of Yuval Filmus' answer, the OP suggested that while, for any two CNF formulas $f$ and $\tilde{f}$,

($f \text{ falsifiable} \iff \tilde{f} \text{ satisfiable}) \iff (f \text{ satisfiable} \iff \tilde{f} \text{ falsifiable}$)

wasn't usually true, it was implied in that specific case by the parsimonious reduction of the CNFFAL instance $f$ to the CNFSAT instance $\tilde{f}$, thus proving that

$f \text{ satisfiable} \iff \Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f} \text{ falsifiable}$.

This answer is supposed to show evidence that it isn't the case (assuming it isn't clear to the reader), as a complement of the previously mentioned answer (per request of the OP in the comments).

---

I'll try to exhibit an example making clear that it isn't the case. Now, building the corresponding $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ of some $f$ would be a bit tedious, so I'll build a parsimonious reduction from CNFFAL to SAT  instead (contrast with the parsimonious reduction from CNFFAL to CNFSAT used in the question), but such that the falsifiability of the SAT instance doesn't imply the satisfiability of the CNFFAL instance.

I claim that, for any CNF formula $f$,
any assignment $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ falsifying $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ allows me to build a unique satisfying assignment of $\tilde{f}(a_1, \dots, a_n, c) =  \lnot f(a_1, \dots, a_n) \land c$ (and vice-versa). This (admittedly dumb) reduction from CNFFAL to SAT preserves the number of solutions so it's parsimonious.

Now let's assume $f(a, b) = (a \lor b) \land (\lnot a \lor b) \land (a \lor \lnot b) \land (\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$.

There indeed are as many ways to falsify $f$ as to satisfy $\tilde{f}$ (4, per the previous parsimonious reduction). Therefore:

$f \text{ falsifiable} \iff \tilde{f} \text{ satisfiable}$

However there also are 4 ways to falsify $\tilde{f}$ (just set $c$ to 0) whereas $f$ is clearly unsatisfiable. Therefore:

$\lnot(f \text{ satisfiable} \iff \tilde{f} \text{ falsfiable})$

Contrast this with that excerpt of the reasoning in the question:

> Therefore $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}\equiv\lnot f$ since Cook and Levin reduction is **parsimonious** and $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is also in **conjunctive normal form**.
>
> Therefore **f** is **falsifiable** if and only if $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is **satisfiable**.
>
> Therefore **f** is **satisfiable** if and only if $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ is **falsifiable**.

---

The previous statement stems from the fact that $\tilde{f}$ uses more variables than $f$, hence the number of possible assignments of $\tilde{f}$ is greater than the number of possible assignments of $f$. Indeed, if those two numbers of possibilities were equal, the reduction being parsimonious would indeed lead to the equivalence of $f$ being satisfiable and $\tilde{f}$ being falsifiable (by a simple counting argument, as the set of falsifiable assignments is the complement of the set of satisfiable assignments).

In the question, $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ has been obtained thanks to Cook-Levin's reduction from an arbitrary NP problem to CNFSAT. That formula doesn't necessarily requires the same amount of variable as $f$ (and is actually very likely to require a far greater amount), so the equivalence doesn't necessarily holds.

Comment: Every **falsifying** assignment of $f$ is **accept** path/route of $NTM_{CNFFAL}$ on $f$ that is **satisfying** assignment of $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ and every **satisfying** assignment of $f$ is **reject** path/route of $NTM_{CNFFAL}$ on $f$ that is **falsifying** assignment of $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$. Even if $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ has more boolean variables, atoms, literals and clauses than **f**, still $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}\equiv\lnot f$, no?

Comment: @user82913 Well not quite but close ! Let's assume you "identify the variables of $f$" inside $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ and that you set them to a falsifying assignment of $f$. Now, there are still other variables you need to set which help to ensure the assignment encodes a correct execution, for instance, describing a state at some instant t... just completely mess with them so that they have incoherent values (for instance the assignement would describe a machine in two different states at the same time). That way, you have $\lnot f$ true but $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ false.

Comment: But $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ can still be helpful to decide the satisfiability of **f** somehow, no?

Answer (score 10):

Every CNF is falsifiable (choose a clause and choose a truth assignment which falsifies it). Unfortunately, the opposite of "CNF $\varphi$ is satisfiable" is not "CNF $\varphi$ is falsifiable". Rather, it is "CNF $\varphi$ is not satisfiable".

Also, even the two were opposites, your proof would only show that NP=coNP, which is not known to imply that P=NP.

Comment: I agree with the error, but I just want to clarify your last remark : you're saying that if "satisfiable" was equivalent to "not falsifiable" and that an arbitrary CNF formula wasn't trivially falsifiable (implicitly implied because the converse would be very weird with the previous assumption), then it would only prove NP=coNP. Correct ?

Comment: Right, it would only show that NP=coNP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus your answer is correct if the logical equivalence in my question doesn't hold and if the logical equivalence doesn't hold then Cook and Levin reduction is **not** parsimonious.

Comment: @user82913 Actually, I thought the Cook-Levin theorem was a reduction of any NP problem to SAT (and not necessarily CNFSAT) and I'm not sure there is a parsimonious reduction from SAT to CNFSAT. But maybe I'm misremembering things. At least, your reasoning has to fail somewhere because if it's correct, it also proves CNF formulas are both falsifiable and satisfiable which sounds very wrong.

Comment: Why do you think that this is wrong that CNF formula can be both falsifiable and satisfiable in the same time? This is indeed possible. $p\lor q$ is both falsifiable and satisfiable. p=false and q=false proves that it is **falsifiable**. p=true and q=false proves that it is **satisfiable** and $p\lor q$ is in conjunctive normal form and it contains a single clause of two positive literals. You see? there exists CNF formula that is both satisfiable and falsifiable.

Comment: @user82913 i don't think it's wrong that a CNF formula is both falsifiable and satisfiable. The problem is that you prove that **all** of them are.

Comment: @user82913 Ah sorry, I think I know why even if you assume that CNFSAT is parsimonious (which it might actually be, contrary to what I remembered, that's not the problem) your equivalence doesn't hold. The number of accepting paths for $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ certainly is the same as the number of ways to falsify $f$. The thing is, $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ and $f$ don't necessarily have the same size, so the number of ways to falsify $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ isn't necessarily the same as the number of ways to satisfy $f$, in particular, the former might be far greater than the later (0).

Comment: @Caninonos I didn't understand your last comment. Can you better explain what are you trying to say? I don't understand why the logical equivalence doesn't hold.

Comment: @user82913 I'll try to give you an example. Now, building the corresponding $\Phi_{NTM_{CNFFAL},f}$ of some $f$ would be a bit tedious so instead I'll build a far simpler (and dumber) parsimonious reduction (from CNFFAL to SAT here). I claim that, for any CNF formula $f$, any assignment $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ falsifying $f(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ allows me to build a unique satisfying assignment of $\tilde{f}(a_1, \dots, a_n, c) =  (\lnot f(a_1, \dots, a_n)) \land c$ (and vice-versa). It preserves the number of solutions so it's parsimonious.

Comment: @user82913 Now let's assume $f(a, b) = (a \lor b) \land (\lnot a \lor b) \land (a \lor \lnot b) \land (\lnot a \lor \lnot b)$, $f$ is clearly unsatisfiable. The thing is, while there indeed are as many ways to falsify $f$ as to satisfy $\tilde{f}$ (4, per the previous parsimonious "reduction"), there are also 4 ways to falsify $\tilde{f}$ (just set $c$ to false) while there are no ways to satisfy $f$. That stems from the fact that $\tilde{f}$ uses more variables than $f$ (and the Cook-Levin reduction would certainly introduce a lot more variables than you had in your original formula)

Comment: @Caninonos Can you post as answer rather than in comments?